# R system call failing due to arithmetic operator

Tags: r, command-line, fasttext

I am trying to mimic the results of a fasttext command line operation in R using the system function. When I run the prompt in the command line I get the desired results as below:

```
F:\>fasttext print-sentence-vectors model.bin < sentences.txt
   0.072631 0.036104 0.0046829 0.057456 0.03449
```

When I try to mimic this in R I get the following:

```
> system("fasttext print-sentence-vectors model.bin < sentences.txt")
  usage: fasttext print-sentence-vectors <model>

  <model>      model filename

  [1] 1
```

I believe the issue is the requirement of "<" in the command line since when I remove it from the command line prompt I get

```
F:\>fasttext print-sentence-vectors model.bin sentences.txt
usage: fasttext print-sentence-vectors <model>

<model>      model filename
```

Same as what I get in R.
So my question is, how do I go about resolving this in R ? I tried various versions with the paste function as well as wrapping the < in quotes but nothing seemed to work.

Tried shell() as per a comment below and got this error message

```
> shell("fasttext print-sentence-vectors model.bin < sentences.txt")
'\\mypathname\fasttextstuff'
CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
The system cannot find the file specified.
Warning message:
In shell("fasttext print-sentence-vectors model.bin < sentences.txt") :
  'fasttext print-sentence-vectors model.bin < sentences.txt' execution failed with error code 1
```

Turns out shell() worked as per the comment below with a directory change.

Comment: The redirection symbol `<` is handled by your command shell, not by `fasttext`.  It looks as though you are on Windows, and on that OS R doesn't run a shell when running `system()`.  Use `shell()` instead.

Comment: Tried that, didn't work, will edit question with the error message

Comment: Looks like your current directory is something that CMD.EXE doesn't support.  It's been a long time since I used Windows, so I don't know the current workarounds.  In the old days you'd set up a drive letter for the UNC path, and use something like `cd D:` to make it current.

Comment: Ahh yea changed the directory and it works now. Thanks

Comment: If the comments have helped you solve your own question you are encouraged to write and post an answer (rather than editing your question to include the answer)

Comment: I mean, the comment answered the question, wouldn't it be more appropriate for the commenter to write the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The redirection symbol `<` is handled by your command shell, not by `fasttext`. It looks as though you are on Windows, and on that OS R doesn't run a shell when running `system()`. Use `shell()` instead.

After that failed, this fixes it:  make sure that your current directory uses a drive letter (e.g. `D:`), not a UNC path, which `CMD.EXE` doesn't like.